# How to detect the disk full error and let program resume after getting free disk space

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems

I am writing an application to run on LINUX, which writes to disk with fprintf & fwrite. I would like to be able to trap "disk full" errors, prompt the user to make more space and then resume operation as if nothing had happened. Is there any graceful solution for it?

Comment: `C` or `C++`? it's not the same, and answers won't either.

Comment: Essentially, no.  In 99% of all household 'disk full' exceptions, you're stuft.

Comment: You propably want to use unbuffered `write()` instead of buffered `fwrite()`. `fprintf()` would then be replaced by a combination of `sprintf()` followed by a `write()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reserve space in larger chunks (say, 64kB or 1MB) and use custom wrappers for `fwrite` and `fprintf` to make sure that data is written only in the already reserved area. These wrappers would also allocate new disk space for your files as necessary. Then, you'll have only a few points in your code where the "out of disk space" can actually happen, and this error is relatively easy to recover from if you know you only have been allocating.

Comment: @tianya: Actually, even simpler: If you know the size of the target file in advance, you can preallocate the entire space. This is what, e.g., Windows Explorer and some download managers do.

Answer (score 5):

Check the return value of each call to `fprintf()` and `fwrite()`.  If either call returns a negative value, check `errno` to see if `errno` is equal to `EDQUOT` or `ENOSPC`, see [manpage for write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write/) (or in case of `fprintf()` maybe even `ENOMEM`, as mentioned in [some manpages for fprintf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fprintf/) but not [in all](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf/)).  If so, you're probably out of disk space.

As for resuming the operation as if nothing ever happened; that's a little bit harder; you'll need to keep track of what data you successfully wrote to the disk, so that after you've notified the user and they've indicated that it's time to try again, you can resume writing that data from the point at which the error occurred.  That means keeping the state of the write in a structure of some sort (i.e. not just on the stack) so that you can return from your writing-function and then resume it later on.  (Either that, or do the writing in a separate thread, and have the thread notify the main thread and then block until the main thread notifies back that it's safe to continue... that might get a little tricky though)

Comment: fclose() also, no? I seem to remember that fwrite() may be successful while it actually only wrote to the internal buffers. Only fclose() actually writes everything, then detecting the disk full.

Comment: @bortzmeyer Yeah that too... although I'm not sure how you'd recover cleanly from an error returned by fclose(), since it would be difficult to know how much data was written before the error occurred!  Perhaps by examining the length of the written file...  or it might be easier to just avoid the C buffering mechanisms altogether by calling write() instead of fwrite() or fprintf().

Comment: Yes, we can find writing error by checking the returned value of those two functions calls. However, since fprintf & fwrite should be buffered I/O functions, will we lost the data we have written before? If yes, how can we make the binary consume when there is enough space?

Comment: ENOMEM is for memory. ENOSPC is for disk

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I'm going by what 'man fprintf' says it will return...  "[ENOMEM] == Insufficient storage space is available"

Comment: @tianya You are write, the buffering layer might be a problem.  As I said in my comment above, you could avoid the buffering layer by calling write() directly instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use [boost](http://www.boost.org/) library then is pretty simple.

[boost::filesystem::space](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#space) returns information about disk space. Input to space method is path to the file, and result is space_info structure which contains capacity, free space and available space. More about space_info is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#space_info).

Comment: Wrong algorithm: on a multi-user machine, the disk can be filled by another process between your call to boost::filesystem::space and the moment you write.

Comment: Check the disk status is not the bottleneck, and disk might be used by other processors or users at the same time my application is running. Then, though we find the space is enough when it begins to write, the application might encounter disk-not-enough issue too.

Comment: I pose the counter argument that you can check if disk space is even close.  That gives a three way option of "there's so much space that it's highly unlikely that the disk will be full by the time the write happens", "There is enough space, but it's going to be close; warn the user to be careful", and "there is definitely not enough space".